# "ERROR:MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.files index: key_1 dup key: { key: null }"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to intergrate in my api the possibility to create a user. I'm using node and mongodb. Here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const FileSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength:1,
        unique:false,
    }, extension: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:false,
    }, content: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:false,
    },group:{
        type:String,
        required:false,
        unique:false,
    }, creator:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique:false,
    }
})

const File = mongoose.model('File', FileSchema);

module.exports = File;
```

And here is my function:

```
const createNewFile = (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const extension = req.body.extension;
    const creator = req.body.creator;
    const group = req.body.group;
    console.log(req.body)

    const newFile = new File({name, extension, content:'Write your code here',creator, group:group});

    newFile.save()
        .then(() => res.json('200'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('ERROR:'+err))
}
```

And the Insomia and Postman console returns the error that is in the title. What can I do to  avoid this error? I added `unique: false` because I read it in another quesion , but it failed anyway. Can someone please help me? When the db is empty, I can create the first element. Then, when I create the second one, the errors arrives. PLease help me

Comment: It looks like you have an index on the File collection. Could you share all of your indexes here? If you made changes to your File model, you may have to drop the whole collection to get rid of old indexes

Comment: Have you tried https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.syncIndexes method drop unused indexes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the mongodb node there is a unique index on `{key: 1}` in the `files` collection of the `myFirstDatabase` database.

I suspect this was created when you were testing potential schema designs.

In order to insert documents that do not contain unique values for that field, including not including the field, that index will need to be removed.

Several ways to accomplish that:

- connect to mongod with the mongo shell, or admin tool like Compass or Robo3t and drop the index manually
- use `syncIndexes` provided by Mongoose
- drop the `files` collection
- drop the `myFirstDatabase` database
- stop the mongod, remove the entire dbpath, and start over with a clean instance